# How to refer to multiple SQL Server databases in app.config connection string

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, connection-string, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am running SQL Server unit tests and have two test databases on which I want to test, "A" and "B". In my VSTS Release definition, I deploy my DACPAC files for both of these test DBs to the **same server**. In my app.config file that is copied to the build output, I have the following connection string, which references database "A" as the "Initial Catalog":

```
<SqlUnitTesting>
    <DataGeneration ClearDatabase="true" />
    <ExecutionContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=XYZ;Initial Catalog=A;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        CommandTimeout="30000" />
    <PrivilegedContext Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString="Data Source=XYZ;Initial Catalog=A;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        CommandTimeout="30000" />
</SqlUnitTesting>
```

If I also want to connect to database "B", how can I do this?

- Could I create two Initial Catalogs in the same connection string?
- Could I create two configSections, where one has the connection string refer to "A" and the other refers to "B"?
- Could I remove Initial Catalog from my connection string so that it does not only limit me to "A"?
- Could I create two app.config files and have them in the same location?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I learned that each project has its own app.config, and when the projects build, they are outputted as .dll.config files. In each one of those, I specify the same server, but I use the different databases as the Initial Catalog values. By doing this, each project looks at its respective .dll.config and the db connections are successfully established.